# What to do if Windows Dev Center rejects a package because of package version?

Tags: uwp, windows-dev-center

[image: Error]

---

Hello! I am trying to upload a package to the Windows Store. However, when I upload my packages, I get this error.

**Smart Team Builder_1.1.3.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload 21.4 MB**

- Your package Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6 specifies version 1.6.25512.0, but 1.6.24903.0 is the minimum available version.
- Your package Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7 specifies version 1.7.25412.0, but 1.7.25304.0 is the minimum available version.

I tried to add these lines to my `Package.appxmanifest` by following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38609326/5083247) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38594736/5083247), but I get the same error.

```
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6" MinVersion="1.6.25512.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7" MinVersion="1.7.25412.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
```

So... How do I fix that?

Comment: Did you try replacing minimum version you specified (1.6.25512.0) with the suggested version (1.6.24903.0 ) ??

Comment: That's exactly my question, how do I do that? I tried to use both `1.6.25512.0` and `1.6.24903.0` in my `PackageDependency`, but I got the same error. How do I lower these package dependencies?

Comment: Are you building with a released SDK or an Insider SDK?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview and I have Windows 10 Insider Preview. As for the content (sdk) of this version of Visual Studio, I have no idea; I just used the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your `Package.appxmanifest`

```
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6" MinVersion="1.6.24903.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />

<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7" MinVersion="1.7.25304.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
```