# Dependency on .NET Native - missing package

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38609326/6065875) to fix an error, that occured, when I was compiling with .NET Native.

The problem with compiling with .NET Native is

```
2>  Starting .NET Native compilation
2>  Processing application code
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: Objektreferencen er ikke indstillet til en forekomst af et objekt. {translated: Object reference not set to an instance of an object}
```

But when I added the `PackageDependency`, this error occured, when I was going to do a certification, this error occured:

[image: Windows App Certification error]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not the right way to do it.  This package is added when the Store server rebuilds your app package to make it suitable for download.  You only have .NET Native on your machine to test your program, there are many things that can go wrong so testing the native build is very important.  You must run WACK on the regular non-native build of your app, the one you actually submit to the Store.

Comment: It was the one, I was going to submit to the Store. But as I have to build without .NET Native due to a bug in Xamarin, I have disabled this in the build process. But I am using .NET Native other places in my code, so I have to include it.

Comment: "I followed this guide to fix an error, that occured, when I was compiling with .NET Native." What is your original error? "But as I have to build without .NET Native due to a bug in Xamarin, I have disabled this in the build process.", could you please post a screenshot or something whicn can describe this bug?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT The problem with .NET Native is now added in the question.

Comment: @LasseMadsen, seems your project could not pass the .net native compiling, could you please check this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/698ad99c-ef9e-4060-afc6-f9e2f0b4ef69/uwpuwp-net-native-compile-error-on-assemblyclosuretask-in-preresolvetransforms?forum=wpdevelop)? There are many possibilities which can cause your problem, but I think adding PackageDependency could not solve this problem?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I think the problem is, that I am using XAML in Xamarin PCL. Xamarin's support told me to use the `PackageDependency`.

Comment: @LasseMadsen So did you get this suggestion from Xamarin forum or contact with their support directly? Do you mean that the xamarin PCL project can't be compiled successfully in Release mode?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT From their support directly. It can't be compiled successfully in Release mode with .NET Native on. If .NET Native is deactivated, it compiles fine but fails in certification.

Answer (score -1):

It's seem you are missing the .NET framework on your PC. Are you using visual studio 2015? If I am not wrong you need to certificate your APP to publish in the store.

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. And that happened, when I was going to validate the package on my pc.

Comment: and do you have installed this component? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/mt637082.aspx

Comment: It is in the SDK, so yes